# server isn't responding when started with procmon

Tags: fuzzing, process-monitoring, boofuzz

I'm using  boofuzz 0.1.6 on an Ubuntu machine. I'm trying to get the process_monitor_unix to connect to the server programm I want to fuzz. When I start procmon and my script, I get the following output on procmon:

```
[05:47.20] Process Monitor PED-RPC server initialized:
[05:47.20]   listening on:  0.0.0.0:26002
[05:47.20]   crash file:    /home/rico/PycharmProjects/iec104_server_fuzz/boofuzz-crash-bin
[05:47.20]   # records:     0
[05:47.20]   proc name:     None
[05:47.20]   log level:     1
[05:47.20] awaiting requests...
[05:47.24] updating target process name to './simple_server'
[05:47.24] updating stop commands to: [u'kill -SIGINT $(pidof simple_server)']
[05:47.24] updating start commands to: [u'/home/rico/iec60870/lib60870-master/lib60870-C/examples/cs104_server/simple_server']
[05:47.24] updating crash bin filename to 'boofuzz-crash-bin-2020-03-19T16-47-24'
[05:47.24] Starting target...
[05:47.24] starting target process
[05:47.24] done. waiting for start command to terminate.
APCI parameters:
 t0: 10
 t1: 15
 t2: 10
 t3: 20
 k: 12
 w: 8
```

The output "APCI parameters ..." is a message of the server which is send everytime the server is started. Therefore I think it's up and running. My problem is that it isn't responding to incoming tcp-packages. 
The output of my fuzzscript is the following:

```
[2020-03-19 17:47:24,314]     Info: Web interface can be found at http://localhost:26000
[2020-03-19 17:47:24,316] Test Case: 1: activate->s_formatAPDU.no-name.1 
[2020-03-19 17:47:24,316]     Info: Type: Bytes. Default value: b'\x91\xef\xa5'. Case 1 of 270 overall.
[2020-03-19 17:47:24,316]   Test Step: Calling procmon pre_send()
```

It get's stuck in this test  step.
When I start the server first, then procmon, then the fuzzscript, I get the following error:

```
[10:29.51] Process Monitor PED-RPC server initialized:
[10:29.51]   listening on:  0.0.0.0:26002
[10:29.51]   crash file:    /home/rico/PycharmProjects/iec104_server_fuzz/boofuzz-crash-bin
[10:29.51]   # records:     0
[10:29.51]   proc name:     None
[10:29.51]   log level:     1
[10:29.51] awaiting requests...
[10:29.55] updating target process name to './simple_server'
[10:29.55] updating stop commands to: [u'kill -SIGINT $(pidof simple_server)']
[10:29.55] updating start commands to: [u'/home/rico/iec60870/lib60870-master/lib60870-C/examples/cs104_server/simple_server']
[10:29.55] updating crash bin filename to 'boofuzz-crash-bin-2020-03-19T21-29-55'
[10:29.55] Starting target...
[10:29.55] starting target process
[10:29.55] done. waiting for start command to terminate.
APCI parameters:
 t0: 10
 t1: 15
 t2: 10
 t3: 20
 k: 12
 w: 8
 Starting server failed!
 [10:29.56] searching for process by name "./simple_server"
 Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boofuzz/utils/debugger_thread_simple.py", line 130, in run
self.spawn_target()
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boofuzz/utils/debugger_thread_simple.py", line 115, in spawn_target
self.watch()
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boofuzz/utils/debugger_thread_simple.py", line 166, in watch
for (pid, name) in _enumerate_processes():
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boofuzz/utils/debugger_thread_simple.py", line 36, in _enumerate_processes
yield (pid, psutil.Process(pid).name())
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 346, in __init__
self._init(pid)
File "/home/rico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 386, in _init
raise NoSuchProcess(pid, None, msg)
NoSuchProcess: psutil.NoSuchProcess no process found with pid 21574
```

Now this seems strange to me, because the pid 21574 isn't the pid of the running server-process. Does someone now more about this? Even wild guesses are appreciated!
If you need other infos aswell, I will gladly provide them.

Comment: I would back up and make sure you can fuzz without the process monitor first. So run your start commands manually, then start the fuzzer and see if it works. Based on your description, that may already be the case.

Comment: The next thing I'd do is start the server manually, then use `ps` or a similar tool to inspect the process list and. An example command is `ps -wwauxf` -- you can look around and see what the process name is. If the running server process isn't named "./simple_server", you might want to provide a custom name via your procmon args. Let me know if this gets you any progress!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.
When I search for the process by using `ps aux`, I get the same name as i wrote in my script. I have tried changing it to the full path, and starting the server with the same command I used as start command. Same error. To me, it seems like procmon couldn't attach to the running server.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error by deleting the line
`"proc_name": '/home/rico/iec60870/lib60870-master/lib60870-C/examples/cs104_server/simple_server'` in my fuzzscript. I also had to make sure that the server is !not! already running when I start my fuzzscript.
Now, the server starts in the terminal which runs procmon.

I don't know if there is a better way to fix this, but atleast the procmon can do it's job now.